# how to set where condition on array of reference selection in flutter using Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm from MySql background, new to the firebase cloud database.

[image: database design]

How to select the list of products having zone one?
[image: Zone Collection]

Mysql: `select * from products where product.status=true and zoneIds.name in ("604307") and zoneIds.status=true;`

My Flutter code

```
class DatabaseManager {

  final CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');
  
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStream() {
    return collection.where('status', isEqualTo: true).snapshots();
  }
```

How to add the conditions in this?

```
return collection.where('status', isEqualTo: true).snapshots();
```

Also, suggest to me how to do the foreign key reference concept in firebase

Answer (score 2):

Firestore supports array queries.
You can add the condition something like this:

```dart
return collection
        .where('status', isEqualTo: true)
        .where('zoneIds', arrayContainsAny: ['1'])
        .snapshots();
```

You can refer the FlutterFire documentation on querying [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying).

Comment: need to apply the zone reference status = true condition.